# How should one pronounce the "rofl" in "roflstomp" or "roflcopter"?

Tags: pronunciation, slang, neologisms

"ROFL" stands for [rolling on the floor laughing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOL#Variations_on_the_theme) but has been mushed into other words with their own meanings. Two examples:

> Ouch, that was a roflstomp.
>
> I'm on a roflcopter!

While these are in questionable status as English words, should I pronounce them?

Comment: with the invention of Internet, and the shift to text-based communication as the primary means of communicating, many words are coined that are never meant to be pronounced. I would advise against using them in speech except for discussion about the words themselves. And in those discussions, it is always fun to start with arguing whose pronunciation is right.

Comment: @Lie: Point taken. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ROFL (pronounced /ˈroʊfəl/ or /ˈrɒfəl/)](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/rofl/en-en/):

> Teenagers now sometimes use them in
>   spoken communication as well as in
>   written, with ROFL (pronounced
>   /ˈroʊfəl/ or /ˈrɒfəl/) and LOL
>   (pronounced /ˈloʊl/, /ˈlɒl/, or
>   /ˌɛloʊˈɛl/), for example.

Comment: Can you rhyme that first example with anything? Does /ˈroʊ/ sound like 'low'? If it does..that doesn't sound right!

Comment: +1 purely for finding _some_ outside source with a listed pronunciation but the real source was Wikipedia and that portion was [edited out in May 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=LOL&action=historysubmit&diff=363203873&oldid=363127524) as unsourced. So, good find but unfortunately not very authoritative.

Comment: +1 @MrHen getting a +1 from you is an end in and of itself haha

Comment: @page: Hey now, I've handed out over 400 upvotes... ;)

Comment: @MrHen and you're going to hand out more, right? ;) haha

Comment: I accepted this answer over the others for two reasons: (a) it included IPA and (b) had _some_ form of reference which, albeit not a very good one, was better than the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, you should avoid using them at all in anything formal.  If for some reason you need to discuss them formally, I would say R-O-F-L-copter (spell it out).

Otherwise, think of it as "roffle" (RAW-ful; rhymes with waffle).  I've never heard it pronounced otherwise, whether amongst my nerdy friends or in internet videos.

Comment: I concur with "roffle," but in my idiolect, it doesn't rhyme with "waffle," but sounds more like "rah-ful."

Comment: @the-raven "Rah-ful" rhymes with "waffle", doesn't it?  How are you pronouncing waffle?

Comment: To me, "waffle" rhymes with "awful." Exactly as in the post above, i.e., "RAW-ful." This is why contrastive pairs are so useful in determining English dialect (caught vs cot, bought vs bot, etc.).

Comment: @The Raven: yeah true, in my idiolect, "wish" rhymes with "ghoti"

Comment: @The Raven: I don't merge *cot* with *caught* either, but for me the vowel of *waffle* is the same as that of *father*, which is distinct from both. Even if you merge *father* and *bother*, I find it odd that your *father* and *awful* have the same vowel, assuming your *awful* and *caught* do. I'm guessing you're from the South?

Comment: @JonPurdy Oh no, my "father" and "awful" are not homophonic, but "father" and "bother" are. My idiolect is a blend of Chicago midwest and Northern west coast US. I checked with a Canadian (Toronto area) friend, and she also rhymes "waffle" with "awful." Interesting marker word, no?

Answer (score 1):

Raw-Full. 
roflwaffle.

I don't think their status as words is "questionable". I think it's glaringly obvious that they aren't words. Haha.

Comment: You laugh now, but _doh_ is a word. I suspect _pwn_ will eventually be included as a variant of _own_ and both will include the newer usage. Language will evolve with or without your approval. :)

Comment: Haha, Yeah I know.

Comment: @MikeVaughan: I think the last laugh will indeed be on you. *My* dictionary doesn't even recognise your **Haha** as a word (still hyphenated according to them). And @MrHen - don't get your hopes up for *pwn* yet - let's see if it's still current in a decade or so.

Comment: I know someone who pronounces "pwn". It makes me cringe every time she says it.

Comment: Yeah, @FumbleFingers - I would agree that a lot of the words being referenced here memes and have a high probability of falling out of usage with time. Still, with 'LOL' and others having recently been accepted into the OED, who is to say...

Comment: @Karl: Quite so. Secretly, I'd love 'pwn' to survive. It's etymology must be pretty unique in the modern world. I've always despised obscure archaic words with the tentative origin "possibly a misreading of *xxxxx* in Chaucer / Shakespeare / Spencer". But 'pwn' is in a class of its own.

Answer (score -1):

Old-timey Unix sysadmins laugh at your puny human attempts at pronunciation.

The words are pronounced the way they're spelt. [Yes, spelt. Look it up if you don't believe me.]

With a nod to Victor Borge's phonetic punctuation, Unix geeks in the old days used to be able to pronounce things like "/usr/local/bin/*.exe" or "$PATH" sufficiently unambiguously to be able to help with system installation problems over the phone (before e-mail was common). In particular, the pronunciation of "usr" and "user" was clearly distinguished. Probably it helped that everyone had learnt English through phonics.

Comment: Can you add an explicit pronunciation, though? Otherwise, this doesn't really answer my question. :)